# Make Async Operations prettier in .Net4.0

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task

To preface, I'm 100% stuck using .Net 4.0.

I'm trying to consume a web service, and make the async calls a little less messy for the client to consume.  I came up with:

```
protected void Get<T>(string uri, Action<T> callback)
{
    var client = GetNewClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

    client.SendAsync(request)
        .Completed(t =>
        {
            T resp = t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
            callback(resp);
        })
        .Errored(t =>
        {
            throw t.Exception;
        });
}
```

`Completed` and `Errored` are just extension methods that wrap `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` and `OnlyOnFaulted`, respectively.

This code works well when everything goes as expected.  The problem is, if the task faults (i.e. web service down), the error doesn't make it back to the consumer.  Also, the task is marked as `Completed` even if the response `HttpStatusCode` indicates an error (i.e. 404).  I'd certainly like to handle those situations effectively, with this current implementation I have no way to do so (the response item is simply null).

Is there a way to raise an error back to the consumer here, or should I abandon this approach altogether?

Comment: Why not use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)?

Comment: Why are you going out of your way to turn the `Task` into a callback?  Just return the `Task` that you have.

Comment: I was trying to return the object itself, rather than an `HttpResponseMessage`.  @YuvalItzchakov, great idea, told by management we can't depend on Issue#8 in the known issues.

Comment: Issue 8 says you need to have .NET 4 installed. You said you do. I don't see the problem?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, sorry I wasn't clear.  Under Issue #8 in the resolution section, it requires a specific update package installed.  Apparently we can't guarantee that.  I'm not trying to fight you, it's just the decision made from higher up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to raise an error back to the consumer here, or should I abandon this approach altogether?

Well, take a look at your signature:

```
protected void Get<T>(string uri, Action<T> callback);
```

When the client calls `Get<T>`, it starts the asynchronous operation *and then returns*. Obviously, if there is an exception *later*, there's no way to have the thread travel back in time and return from this method again.

Instead, you need to modify your callback. You can easily do this by adding a second callback delegate:

```
protected void Get<T>(string uri, Action<T> callback, Action<Exception> errorCallback);
```

Now one *or the other* of the callbacks will be called when the operation is complete. But what is this doing, really? Just re-introducing callbacks when you already have promises. So a superior solution would be (updated due to Servy's comment):

```
protected Task<T> Get<T>(string uri)
{
  var client = GetNewClient();
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

  return client.SendAsync(request)
      .ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>())
      .Unwrap();
}
```

---

That said, I do think the *best* approach is to use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. Bundling KB2468871 into the installer is not too hard.

Comment: `SendAsync` *already returns a `Task` according to the question, so he should just return it (or use a continuation if applicable if he has other follow up work) rather than using a TCS to re-create the `Task` he already has.

Comment: thanks Stephen.  You make it very obvious where I was going wrong with my thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Decorate your method with async, call await on your get method:

```
protected async Task<T> Get<T>(string uri)
{
    var client = GetNewClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    // Throws an exception to the user if it was not a successful request.
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await response.ReadAsAsync<T>();
}
```

Comment: Its worth noting that you need the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` to do this, or you can use VS2012 or higher and target C#5 or 6 in VS2015 (not sure if 2012 has a 6 targeting pack).